# Using substring in C# textboxes

Tags: c#, textbox, substring

I wanted to display the remaining characters using a label beside my textbox just in case the user input exceeded the maximum length of characters.

This is my code for remaining characters:

```
private void txtID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int MaxChars = 10 - txtID.Text.Length;
        labelChars.Text = MaxChars.ToString() + " characters remaining.";
    }
```

What I wanted to do now is to prevent the user from entering characters in my textbox when he/she already exceeded the character limit. I'm planning to use the **Substring** property of the textbox but I don't know how. Help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the MaxLength property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the [`MaxLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx) property of the textbox and it will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use the MaxLength property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You know the [`MaxLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx) property?

Answer (score 0):

This would work much better on the client side. Use the MaxLength property of the textbox and maybe a little javascript to keep the lblChars control functioning.

```
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="10" runat="server" ID="txtID" ClientIDMode="Static" onkeydown="changedID();"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ClientIDMode="Static" ID="lblChars" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changedID() {
        var t = document.getElementById("txtID");
        var l = document.getElementById("lblChars");
        l.innerText = (10 - t.value.length) + " characters remaining.";
    }
</script>
```